# Create user (customer) using magento rest api

Tags: php, ios, api, rest, magento

In my iPhone application, I want to `create new user` (sign up/create new account), Is that possible to do? In website it allows to create new user after filling sign up details.

I used rest api and `oauth 1.0` to authenticate. I am able to login successfully from application for customer.

To create new customer, I found this link [Create Customer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Customers-HTTPMethod-POST-customers) but it asks for admin login. Not sure how user can enter admin login.

Please guide me.

Comment: Follow this link to create new customer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439888/creating-a-new-customer-in-magentorestful-php