# Is it possible to send password along with other details in JSON format in Magento 2 REST API for customer registration?

Tags: json, magento

```
 I am trying to register a new Customer to my new magento portal through REST API in Postman, but as per standard approach of Magento API for Registration only following Details can be sent via POST Method password cannot be sent through it. if done so give error as shown below.
```

[Successful Result after POST Method without sending password in JSON Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj8o0.png)

[Failure Page after sending password along with the JSON array in POST Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NMHo.jpg)

Can someone help me with issue how to include password in REST API Customer Registration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

send password in encrypted format like `md5('password')`
May be this is help to you, if this not work then please refere below reference url.

[Creating a new customer in Magento(RESTful,PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439888/creating-a-new-customer-in-magentorestful-php)

Comment: where should i create this PHP? where should i run this PHP from?  @Sunny Rathod

Comment: you can create this file in magento root folder.